# ERC20-Low-Level Implemetation

Tags: erc-20

I recently seen a new implementation of the erc20 standard. although i am new to programming in general its rearly impossible to yet understand the logic behing this code. i was wondering if someone could look at this code and tell me how is this [Low-Level implementation](https://github.com/goncaloMagalhaes/erc20-low-level/blob/develop/src/ERC20PermitInlineAssembly.sol) of the erc20 different from per say OppenZeppelin's implementation?

Comment: The more noticiable difference is that it is implemented using EVM assembly.

Comment: but it does the axact same thing right?